# How to handle redirection in Jhispter when session timeout?

Tags: reactjs, spring, session, okta

My environment:

1. jhispter
2. reactjs front-end with java spring boot
3. Okta for authentication
4. Axios for reactjs web api call

My goal: After the user is authenticated, if the session has been idle for 20 minutes, the session will timeout, and we would like to redirect the user to okta login page if he/she makes any api calls

This is how I have implemented:

1. I use Axios interceptors, and I checks http response, if the response is 401 or 403, I dispatch an action, the the action will set isAuthenticated is redux store to false.
2. I have a hoc (high order component) to wrap up UI component, it checks isAuthenticated, if false, I run  window.location.href = "okta login url";

However, it does not redirect the to login page I expected

My question:

1. Is it the right way to run window.location.href = "okta login url";
2. what is the correct "okta login url" I should put it here?

Comment: If you configure your Okta app to allow refresh tokens, it should automatically refresh access tokens.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you very much for your quick response..

Just want to clarify that if session time out and expired access token are the same thing.

In our case, in spring config, if I add timeout 60 to application.yml, i.e.

server:
  servlet:
    session:
      timeout: 60

Then If I keep the client app idle for 60 seconds, I will receive 401 error, I dont think at the point, the token expired.

Please help to clarify.

Thank you very much for your help.